# How to undo fill-paragraph in emacs?

Tags: emacs, word-wrap

I have a text file that is pretty long. Any easy way to "undo" a `M-q` (fill-paragraph) on a file that was written and saved a while ago?

For example, I want to change this:

> They're coming to take me away,
>   ha-haaa!! 
> They're coming to take me
>   away, ho-ho, hee-hee, ha-haaa
>
> To the funny farm. Where life is
>   beautiful all the time and I'll 
>  be
>   happy to see those nice young men in
>   their clean white 
> coats and they're
>   coming to take me away, ha-haaa!!!!!

To this:

> They're coming to take me away,
>   ha-haaa!! They're coming to take me
>   away, ho-ho, hee-hee, ha-haaa
>
> To the funny farm. Where life is
>   beautiful all the time and I'll be
>   happy to see those nice young men in
>   their clean white coats and they're
>   coming to take me away, ha-haaa!!!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set `fill-columnn` to a really large number, and fill.

```
C-u 10000 C-x f M-x fill-individual-paragraphs
```

Or you can use a little custom function:

```
(defun refill-paragraphs-to-be-one-line ()
  "fill individual paragraphs with large fill column"
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-column 100000))
    (fill-individual-paragraphs (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but a comment: your function appears not to work on paragraphs that start with a symbol such as a dash (-) or an asterisk (*), whereas the functions given by Doug Harris do. Maybe something has changed since you posted this 8 years ago.

Answer (score 22):

Use the following from my .emacs:

```
(defun unfill-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-column (point-max)))
    (fill-paragraph nil)))

(defun unfill-region ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-column (point-max)))
    (fill-region (region-beginning) (region-end) nil)))
```

I can't take credit, I googled this years ago.

Answer (score 2):

When I asked for help on M-Q  (as opposed to M-q) in emacs 24.4.1, I got this:

```
M-Q (translated from <escape> Q) runs the command unfill-paragraph, which is an
interactive Lisp function in `init-util.el'.

It is bound to M-Q.

(unfill-paragraph &optional REGION)

Takes a multi-line paragraph and makes it into a single line of text.
```

Comment: That's probably because you added code from [this page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph) to your Emacs configuration.

Comment: Nope. I found it in modules/init-util.el

Comment: That file is not included in vanilla GNU Emacs. Perhaps it came from your distribution or from a package you installed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that key binding to macOS users that used the Command as their Meta key: Cmd-Q means quit all applications and log out :)  Worth a mention in your answer?

Comment: @dcorking - an edit to satisfy your request was rejected by the powers that be. Your comment will need to serve as the only warning.

Comment: thanks for trying; (there are no powers that be for edit reviews, just fellow users )

Answer (score 1):

```
C-x f 100000 M-q
```

This fills exactly one paragraph.

Explanation:

1. `C-x f Number`: Set a large number (100 000) of characters for the column.
2. `M-q`: Invoke the `fill-paragraph` command. (Alternative for multiple paragraphs: `M-x fill-individual-paragraphs`)

Afterwards, don't forget to revert the column width back to the previous value (here: 78).

```
C-x f 78
```