# Disable auto-fill-mode locally (or un fill-paragraph) with emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, autofill

I use M-q for fill-paragraph, can I do the un-fill-paragraph in auto-fill-mode?

With org mode, I sometimes enter **[[Very long HTML][Name with spaces]]**, and for the 'Name with spaces' the auto-fill mode break the whole line based on the inserted space, which makes it very ugly.

Is there a command something like un-fill-paragraph? Or, is there a way disable auto-fill-mode temporarily/locally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emacs does not record what was your line before calling `fill-paragraph`. So the only thing you can do is <kbd>C-_</kbd> which runs the command undo. It can undo your `fill-paragraph` command but only if it is the preceding command call.

If you want to put a multi-line paragraph on one line you could do like this :

- Select the region
- <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd>C-j</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Xah Lee has updated his code since monotux's answer, and I refactored it somewhat for readability:

```el
(defun my-toggle-fill-paragraph ()
  ;; Based on http://xahlee.org/emacs/modernization_fill-paragraph.html
  "Fill or unfill the current paragraph, depending upon the current line length.
When there is a text selection, act on the region.
See `fill-paragraph' and `fill-region'."
  (interactive)
  ;; We set a property 'currently-filled-p on this command's symbol
  ;; (i.e. on 'my-toggle-fill-paragraph), thus avoiding the need to
  ;; create a variable for remembering the current fill state.
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((deactivate-mark nil)
           (line-length (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position)))
           (currently-filled (if (eq last-command this-command)
                                 (get this-command 'currently-filled-p)
                               (< line-length fill-column)))
           (fill-column (if currently-filled
                            most-positive-fixnum
                          fill-column)))

      (if (region-active-p)
          (fill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
        (fill-paragraph))

      (put this-command 'currently-filled-p (not currently-filled)))))
```

Comment: Linking in related Q&As: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471557/how-to-undo-fill-paragraph-in-emacs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707758/inverse-of-m-q-an-unfill-paragraph-function

Answer (score 2):

To remake a long line out of a paragraph in Org mode, I gave myself a new command.  Here is the associated Emacs Lisp code:

```
(defun fp-unfill-paragraph (&optional justify region)
  (interactive (progn
         (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
         (list (if current-prefix-arg 'full) t)))
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-column 100000))
    (fill-paragraph justify region)))

(global-set-key "\C-ceu" 'fp-unfill-paragraph)
```

Of course, you adjust the command keybinding as you see fit!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following snippet to fill and un-fill paragraphs (using only `M-q`), it is really, really handy. I borrowed it from Xah Lee, but removed some comments and whitespace in order to make it fit in here. The link in the first comment goes to his original code.

```
;; http://xahlee.org/emacs/modernization_fill-paragraph.html
(defun compact-uncompact-block ()
  "Remove or add line endings on the current block of text.
This is similar to a toggle for fill-paragraph and unfill-paragraph
When there is a text selection, act on the region.

When in text mode, a paragraph is considered a block. When in programing
language mode, the block defined by between empty lines.

Todo: The programing language behavior is currently not done.
Right now, the code uses fill* functions, so does not work or work well
in programing lang modes. A proper implementation to compact is replacing
newline chars by space when the newline char is not inside string.
"
  (interactive)
  (let (bds currentLineCharCount currentStateIsCompact
            (bigFillColumnVal 4333999) (deactivate-mark nil))
    (save-excursion
      (setq currentLineCharCount
            (progn
              (setq bds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'line))
              (length (buffer-substring-no-properties (car bds) (cdr bds)))))
      (setq currentStateIsCompact
            (if (eq last-command this-command)
                (get this-command 'stateIsCompact-p)
              (if (> currentLineCharCount fill-column) t nil)))
      (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
          (if currentStateIsCompact
              (fill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
            (let ((fill-column bigFillColumnVal))
              (fill-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
            )
        (if currentStateIsCompact
            (fill-paragraph nil)
          (let ((fill-column bigFillColumnVal))
            (fill-paragraph nil))))
      (put this-command 'stateIsCompact-p
           (if currentStateIsCompact
               nil t)))))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'compact-uncompact-block)
```