# Inverse of M-q, an unfill-paragraph-function

Tags: emacs

Is there an inverse for <kbd>M-q</kbd>, some kind of `unfill-paragraph-function`?

If I have undo data, then it's of course easy. What I am asking for is instead the ability to merge lines in a paragraph into a single long line, right after I have just read the file from disk. This would make it possible to then paste the text into a form (a web form and the like) that is expecting a single linebreak for each paragraph.

In the past I have turned off `auto-fill`, created a macro to delete an EOL and move to the next line, and applied it repeatedly, but this is getting tiring.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Here's the answer](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_unfill-paragraph.html). In short:

```
(defun unfill-paragraph ()
  "Replace newline chars in current paragraph by single spaces.
This command does the reverse of `fill-paragraph'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-column 90002000))
    (fill-paragraph nil)))
 
(defun unfill-region (start end)
  "Replace newline chars in region by single spaces.
This command does the reverse of `fill-region'."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((fill-column 90002000))
    (fill-region start end)))
```

*Update: I've packaged this up [here](https://github.com/purcell/unfill) and it can be installed from [Marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org) or [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net).*

Comment: I'm curious about that integer. Where does it come from, and is there a reason not to use `most-positive-fixnum` instead?

Comment: You'd have to ask the original author, but it's possible that `most-positive-fixnum` doesn't exist in every Emacs version and variant. I'm curious too.

Comment: Great link. From the same source, comment-uncomment-block is even better: http://xahlee.org/emacs/modernization_fill-paragraph.html That's going to be my new default M-q command.

Answer (score 11):

See also M-^ (delete-indentation).

It joins the current line to the previous line, so if you start with point at the last line of the paragraph you can keep pressing M-^ until all the lines are joined up.

Comment: This approach doesn't take into account things like comment syntax, although it *is* at least smart enough to insert spaces after appropriate punctuation (depending on mode).

Comment: phils: "If there is a fill prefix, delete it from the beginning of this line". With point at the first non-fill-prefix column you can use C-x . (set-fill-prefix) and then M-^ will work the way you want. It's a shame that M-^ doesn't figure out the fill-prefix on its own, like M-q does.

Answer (score 1):

I was first using @sanityinc's solution for a while until I came accross [Stefan Monnier's Unfill Paragraph in EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph). It seems more robust

```
;;; Stefan Monnier <foo at acm.org>. It is the opposite of fill-paragraph    
(defun unfill-paragraph (&optional region)
  "Takes a multi-line paragraph and makes it into a single line of text."
  (interactive (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only) '(t)))
  (let ((fill-column (point-max))
        ;; This would override `fill-column' if it's an integer.
        (emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column t))
    (fill-paragraph nil region)))

;; Handy key definition
(define-key global-map "\M-Q" 'unfill-paragraph)
```

The `M-Q` key binding makes the command so much easier.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that key binding to macOS users that used the Command as their Meta key: Cmd-Q means quit all applications and log out :)  Worth a mention in your answer?

Comment: @dcorking Agreed. However, I wouldn't recommend using the Mac command key to meta binding at all (prefer option key instead). Because M-q is an existing binding to fill paragraph (with region), it would make sense to make M-Q for the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Also see this post

http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2010/03/03/unfill-region-emacs.html

Which mentions the very useful longlines mode.