# What is the canonical command to remove newlines within a paragraph?

Tags: emacs

Is there some command I am missing? Something like M-q (fill-paragraph)? Otherwise I do M-% C-q C-j Return Space Return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `unfill-paragraph`; there's also `unfill-region`.

Comment: On [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6707838/319698), on [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph)

Comment: @false "Where is it"? `M-x unfill-paragraph`, most likely; 23.3 is three years and one major version out of date (24.4 is coming Any Day Now™), but even so, I seem to recall it having this command. If not, you can get both of them from @npostav's Stack Overflow link, and add them to your Emacs init code.